# Blob Storage Access 403

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-blob-storage, azure-cli

I am trying to list the blobs in an existing container via a .net application but I get a 403 AuthorizationFailure error.

The storage account is restricted to a set of corporate IPs. My computer and account has access and I am able to run "`az login`" and  "`az storage blob list --container-name <container> --account-name <account> --auth-mode login`" locally. However when I try to list the some container using C# code, I get a 403 AuthorizationFailure error. The code is:

```
            blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(
                    new Uri($"https://{accountName}.blob.core.windows.net/"),
                    new DefaultAzureCredential());
            containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(containerName);
            
            Console.WriteLine("Listing blobs...");
            await foreach (BlobItem blob in containerClient.GetBlobsAsync())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\t" + blob.Name);
            }
```

I am logged in to Visual Studio. I have also tried using `InteractiveBrowserCredential()` which opens a browser and allows me to select my account, and I have tried `AzureCliCredential()` running in the same command instance that works correctly with the "`az ... list`" command above.

Why does it work via the Azure CLI tool but not the sample code?

Comment: Are you using `Managed Identity` with `DefaultAzureCredential`, if yes please make sure the managed identity has enough permissions.

Comment: I am using my own developer identity at the moment, it has permissions to do it via the CLI but not via the code sample it appears

Comment: Do you have the detailled error ? Are you debugging using visual studio / vs code ?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have assigned the role `storage Blob Data Contributor` to your azure account. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-dotnet?tabs=visual-studio%2Cmanaged-identity%2Croles-azure-portal%2Csign-in-azure-cli%2Cidentity-visual-studio#assign-roles-to-your-azure-ad-user-account

Comment: I have, and surely it wouldn't work via the Azure CLI if I didn't?